# Place operation times out

Tags: ros, moveit, pick-and-place

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good afternoon,

I was trying to use the pick_place_tutorial tutorial, in pr2_moveit_tutorials, and I am able to pick the object successfully, but the place operation always times out. I don't know why this is happening. Has anyone had a similar problem before?

`[ WARN] [1370458323.163467101, 1184.034000000]: Fail: ABORTED: Timeout reached`

If you need any more information just ask for it please.

Thank you,
Tiago Pimentel

-------------------------   edit   -------------------------

I figured it out, the computer was just really slow, but if I change the position of the pole in 0.05 m.u. forward it can plan correctly.

Change line:

```
co.primitive_poses[0].position.x = 0.7;
```

for this:

```
co.primitive_poses[0].position.x = 0.75;
```

Have a great day,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64403/place-operation-times-out/) by [t.pimentel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4923/t.pimentel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2013-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest posting this to the [MoveIt! mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/moveit-users), as there is quite a bit of activity over there

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [t.pimentel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4923/t.pimentel/) on 2013-06-06**:
Thanks, I posted the question there already, but I found the answer by myself, I'll just edit the question with it.